# Spring MVC + AngularJS change view

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Angular, and I've got a problem. I need to use angularjs to change views in my application, but I don't know how to. I tried to sent http GET request to @controller, that returns needed view (jsp), but it doesn't work:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $http.post("/result")
}
```

This function returns HTML code of required view. Is there a method that allows to change view based on received html?

Comment: First of all, is you Java MVC produce `.jsp` pages?

Comment: AngularJS apps are supposed to be single-page apps. You change a view in an AngularJS app by navigating to a new route, configured in the Angular router. Not by sending an AJAX request to the server. In a proper AngularJS application, your server shouldn't have views at all. It should only serve the static assets needed by AngularJS, and expose REST services.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but this task is like a student's homework, and it should be like that (send a request to get a view).

Comment: And server produces .jsp

Comment: Then why do you use AngularJS? Just use a good old link: `<a target="_self" href="/result">Click here</a>`

Comment: Omg, thanks, I feel quite stupid)